# Create an artboard automatically to the size of an image (Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, images, artboard

I am trying to figure out how to make an artboard automatically snap to the size of an image.

I know that you can draw a rectangle, then go to the Artboards window and choose "Convert to Artboards" from the flyout menu with the rectangle(s) selected. This does not work for images. The problem I have is that I have about 25 images that I've placed into an Illustrator document (buttons for the design of a site) and need to have them all be in their own artboards. Of course I could do this by hand but I was wondering, for future reference, if there is a way just select the image and have an artboard created to its dimensions.

I couldn't find an answer everywhere (all searches took me to how to make a rectangle an artboard, not an image).

Thanks!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use the Artboard tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) and double-click the image, the artboard size will snap to the image dimensions.

Comment: If you're trying to create an artboard on and existing artboard (it does have it's uses), you have to hold a modifier key. Shift, I believe.

Comment: Thanks.I tried these tips,but still when exporting the artboard as svg, the image gets cropped.I have tried to untag the 'align to pixel grid' too,but it did not help.
I have many artboards in my file because I am building an icon library.Can you recommend any other tricks for snapping the image to the artboard? Thanks in advance! ![cropped svg](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9lQl9.png)

Comment: Found I sometimes just needed to select what I wanted, then click on the Artboard tool, then choose Artboard menu on top's Presets drop-down menu -> "Fit to Selected Art"

Answer (score 14):

1) Open image in Illustrator
2) Object/Artboards/Fit to Artwork Bounds

Answer (score 0):

In case you still havent got it. You just select the artboard tool and double click on the image. The artboard gets created automatically behind that image.:)
and then for the next 24 images you just click once on them.