# Is there a shortcut or automated way to create a rectangle the same size of a picture on Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, automation, shortcuts

I have many imported images on Illustrator and would like to create a rectangle with the same size of each, and on the same layout, without clicking on every picture and then "Transform", noting down the dimensions, etc.

Is there a way to create a rectangle the same way you can [create an Artboard by clicking on an image or a group](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/13299/14281)?

Comment: Why do you need these rectangles? (You maybe able to do what you need *without* creating actual objects)

Comment: To create a wireframe, ideally to have them colored and put some text on them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably achieve what you want without creating any actual objects by using the appearance panel (*Window → Appearance*).

Adding strokes and fills to an image doesn't really work so you need to add a "Convert to Shape → Rectangle" effect first, then you can add as many strokes, fills or effects to get what you want. See this for example (duplicated the plain image I used above for reference):

[image]

An example of what you can achieve with a single image with the appearance panel (more suitable for a wireframe, as you mentioned in comments):

[image]

Once you have your appearance the way you like it you can drag the object to the graphic styles panel and reuse it on all your other images with a single click.

Answer (score -1):

The method I have always used:

1. Select your picture and mask it.
2. Mask remains selected. Press <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy it.
3. Undo.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to paste the mask rectangle on top.